# Update Azure VM running Windows 10 Enterprise N to build 14267?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, azure

I have Windows 10 Enterprise N running in an Azure VM and I'd like to update it to a newer build so I can try out Bash for Windows.

It's setup to receive Insider Preview builds and its set to the "Fast" level.  Developer mode is also selected.

Is it possible to update to a newer build that can run Bash for Windows?  I'm not sure what I'm missing.